# Handling dynamic elements in flutter

Tags: flutter, response

I had an old code taking a response (of type List) and I used to handle it in an ugly way, knowing that the response is a big array.

```
List<CsC> newList = new List<CsC>();
if (response[0].length > 0) {
  for (int i = 0; i < response[0].length; i++) {
    if ((response[0][i][0] != BigInt.from(0) || i == 0) ||
        (response[0][0][0] != response[0][i][0] && i != 0)) {
      newList.add(CsC(
          response[0][i][0], //BigInt
          response[0][i][1], //String
          response[0][i][2], //String
          response[0][i][3], //String
          response[0][i][4], //BigInt
    }
  }
```

After the some flutter versions update, I am now facing an issue with that solution given that the response is now seen as "dynamic" so I cannot call the constructor anymore.

How is it possible to handle it? I am completely blocked. Even the check response[0].length > 0 had to be replaced by if(response[0] != null). I am now unable to get response[0].length to loop and I am unable to call the constructor of my CsC.

Many thanks..

Comment: Try casting response to `List`: `final responseList = response as List;`. This will still be a `List<dynamic>`. Without knowing more about the code retrieving the response and calling this code, the best I can suggest is casting each variable in similar fashion.

Comment: Many thanks, this is how I actually solved it

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to cast each variable as Lee3 mentioned

```
for(int i=0; i< (response[0] as List).length; ++i){
    newList.add(CsC(
      response[0][i][0] as BigInt,
      response[0][i][1] as String,
      response[0][i][2] as String,
      response[0][i][3] as String,
      response[0][i][4] as BigInt,
    ));
  }
```